# How to load html file in flex 4.6 mobile application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

my issue is i want to load html file in flex mobile application i try many methods to use it through the StageWebView but not working 
sample of my code :

```
                if(StageWebView.isSupported==true){
                stageWebView = new StageWebView();
                stageWebView.stage = this.stage;
                stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(5 , 500, stage.stageWidth, ((stage.stageHeight-90)/4));
                var fPath:String = new File(new File("assets/ads.html").nativePath).url;
                stageWebView.loadURL(fPath);    
                addEventListener(ViewNavigatorEvent.REMOVING,onRemove);
            }
```

Update : the problem solved by using

```
                    var htmlString:String = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" + 
                    "<html><body>" +
                    "<p>Bsmallah</p>" +
                    "</body></html>";
                stageWebView.loadString( htmlString );
```

but i cannot load script in it

then any help for how can i load it
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Does this file rely on JS to run? Are you running iOS? Can you confirm the file exists? We need more info.

Comment: yes , it contains java script and target android and iOS , If any method to run java script only it well be helpful .

Comment: Give this question I asked a few months ago a read. I was having a similar issue with JS not loading. Oddly enough, I solved it by using `loadURL` when `loadString` wasn't working, the opposite of what you did. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144441/using-stagewebview-loadstring-to-display-google-maps-on-air-for-ios

Answer (score -1):

This below line is messed up.

```
new File(new File("assets/ads.html").nativePath).url
```

If you are looking for the current application directory, you can use File.applicationDirectory for getting the current directory, so you can rephrase the above line like below

```
var fPath:String = File.applicationDirectory + "/" + "assets/ads.html";
```

Comment: In the web view it shows :
Web page is not available 
the web page at [objectFile] /assets/ads.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to anew address , If any method to run java script only it well be helpful .

Comment: The line that was originally used is a workaround for the iOS Sandbox. Basically, AIR uses `app://` and `cache://` (and other) prefixes to represent `File.applicationDirectory` and `File.applicationStorageDirectory`. iOS doesn't understand what those URIs mean and cannot load them for that reason. The workaround being used is the correct way to load a URL into iOS.