# Loading a StageWebView shows up blank on my iPad

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to build a Flash AIR app for iOS. As part of this I need to display specific HTML markup dialogs that are loaded into the app itself. I'm creating a StageWebView to display this HTML but it comes up blank every time. The StageWebView is up and visible with the specified dimensions, but there's nothing on it save a white blank page.

The code for loading it is pretty straightforward:

```
_webView = new StageWebView();
_webView.stage = this.stage;
_webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(50, 50, 400, 300);
_webView.loadString(markupString /* String with full HTML page as text */);
```

This gets called every time I need to display one of these dialogs. 
While testing I noticed a LOCATION_CHANGING event fired with a target that looked like this:

http: //adobe.1234567890.apollo.air/

I have no idea at this point what's going on here. Any help so I can get the StageWebView to display properly on iOS devices is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of JS are you loading? I found that was a problem when using `loadString`. It was some security issue. Easiest way I could get around it was to save to disk using `File` and `FileStream` and then loading the file into your `StageWebView` using `loadURL`.

Comment: As a quick follow up, see my previous question relating to my issues loading a Google Maps element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144441/using-stagewebview-loadstring-to-display-google-maps-on-air-for-ios

Comment: I tried writing the HTML contents to a file and loading it that way but I still have the same empty screen. Here is what I tried:

`        var dialogFile:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("dialog.html");
        var filestream:FileStream = new FileStream();
 filestream.open(dialogFile, FileMode.WRITE);
 filestream.writeUTF(markupString);
 filestream.close();
    
 var dialogURL:String = "file://" + dialogFile.nativePath;
 _webView.loadURL(dialogURL);`